# Height of accordian if default very less,unable to increase

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I have a accordian in my code like this-

```
<div id="accordion">
                <g:each in="${[1,2,3,4,5]}" var="data" status="n">
                        <h3>Referal ${n+1}</h3>
                        <div class="sub-menu">
                            <ul class="form_sec">
                                <div class="" style="width:66%">
                                    <g:uploadForm class="${referralMap ? "form-horizontal" : "form-horizontal resumeAdmin"}"
                                                  controller="candidate" action="save" name="createResume1">
                                        <g:hiddenField name="isAjax" value="yes"></g:hiddenField>

                                        <g:render template="/user/form"></g:render>
                                        <g:render template="/userResume/form"
                                                  model="${[inviteDetails: inviteDetails]} , ${[referralMap: referralMap]}"></g:render>
                                    </g:uploadForm>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                </g:each>
            </div>
```

Height of current active accordion is very less(style="height: 31.8px;"),following is html rendered in browser-

```
<div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" role="tablist">
<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
<div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" style="height: 31.8px;" role="tabpanel">
```

I tried with various combination as-

> $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ heightStyle: "content" });

And-

> #accordion li:target > .sub-menu {
>           min-height: 908px; //add your height here
>       background: red; //add a background color what you would like
>       }

but unable to increase its default height?

II-

by default I want last accordion as active but this rendering first accordion active.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: If you have a `height` inside a style attribute, that's not easy to override in a stylesheet. Why is the style attribute there and can't you get rid of it?

Comment: @MrLister this style is not in my CSS, this is appended by .accordion() method of jQuery over active/inactive panel. but i am not sure since i dig in all css file imported in my page i not found any such css,more over i inlined style over my ul tag,still hight of 32 px is rendering at browser.